# Is is possible to summarize data from 3 unlinked subreports using cross tab feature in crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I am using crystal Reports 2013. I have a main report that comprises of 3 subreports that are not linked. I want to know if I can use the cross tab feature to summarize details from the subreports in the main report.

To be more specific, the three subreports are for New, Open, and Closed anomalies during a test cycle:

These reports have the following fields:
[IssueID]     [Symptom]        [Priority]            [Date]

In the main report I want a summary that would show me a count of issues by priority that were closed, new and open after a test cycle.

So summary will be something like below:

Total       Closed(subreport1)        New(subreport2)       Open(subreport3)

A

B

C

D

Comment: use shared variables to get those values out from subreports

Comment: I don't think `crosstab` will fit your requirement but you can get display using shared variables